# Make a string only show two decimal places in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have array of values:

```
@[@"10",@"11",@"45.56",@"34"]
```

I need  output like this:

```
@[@"10.00",@"11.00",@"45.56",@"34.00"]
```

How can I have this done? I tried:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.00", someDigit];
```

But it didn't work for `@"45.56"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arr=@[@"10",@"11",@"45.56",@"34"];

NSMutableArray *resultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString *string in arr)
{
    [resultArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[string floatValue]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

**Output:**

> (
>       "10.00",
>       "11.00",
>       "45.56",
>       "34.00"
>   )

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
NSString *strFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", someDigit];
```